# How to add a delegate to an interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I need to have some delegates in my class.

I'd like to use the interface to "remind" me to set these delegates.

How to?

My class look like this:

```
public class ClsPictures : myInterface
{
    // Implementing the IProcess interface
    public event UpdateStatusEventHandler UpdateStatusText;
    public delegate void UpdateStatusEventHandler(string Status);

    public event StartedEventHandler Started;
    public delegate void StartedEventHandler();
}
```

I need an interface to force those delegates:

```
public interface myInterface
{
   // ?????
}
```

Answer (score 174):

Those are declaring delegate *types*. They don't belong in an interface. The events *using* those delegate types are fine to be in the interface though:

```
public delegate void UpdateStatusEventHandler(string status);
public delegate void StartedEventHandler();

public interface IMyInterface
{       
    event UpdateStatusEventHandler StatusUpdated;    
    event StartedEventHandler Started;
}
```

The implementation won't (and shouldn't) redeclare the delegate type, any more than it would redeclare any other type used in an interface.

Comment: This just isn't working for me. I'm positive I've done everything this way, and yet, my handler within my interface isn't getting recognised. My class that implements the interface is complaining that the class does not match the interface return type of System.EventHandler.

Comment: @Chucky: Sounds like you should ask a new question with a short but complete example demosntrating the problem. The answer I've given really *does* work.

Comment: I didn't realize that delegates have same level of accessibility as classes. I always thought that they needed to be encapsulated within a class.

Comment: @Purusartha: That's not accessibility - that's just a matter of delegates being types (classes, in fact) just as much as interfaces etc.

Answer (score 38):

Since .NET 3.5 you can also use the System.Action delegates, without the need to declare your own type.

This would result in the following interface:

```
public interface myInterface
{       
   // Implementing the IProcess interface
   event Action<String> UpdateStatusText;

   event Action Started;
}
```

Comment: +1. I find Action/Func to be far more elegant (and readable) than traditional delegate types _and_ you can define them in your interface.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question (how to implement myInterface).

Comment: An issue with using `Action` delegates in an interface is that it's not obvious from the type parameters what the parameter represents which is probably ok and may be obvious with a single parameter but when there are more than one it quickly gets confusing. A delegate type under those circumstances is better.

Comment: I agree with David, say you have `Func<string, int, Task> ExecuteQuery { get; }` It may be obvious what the string value is, but what is the int? With a delegate you could better define it like `public delegate Task ExecuteQueryHandler(string query, int timeout);` Now it's 100% clear what each parameter is.

Answer (score 19):

Just expose the delegate as a property

```
public delegate void UpdateStatusEventHandler(string status);
public delegate void StartedEventHandler();

public interface IMyInterface
{       
    UpdateStatusEventHandler StatusUpdated {get; set;}    
    StartedEventHandler Started {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Jon Skeet's answer is right, I just want to add a note.

Interfaces are not there for "reminding" you what to do, or what to include in your classes. Interfaces are means of abstraction, used in Object Oriented programming and design methods. Maybe you don't need an interface declaration at all, unless you want to see some concrete class instances as the interface elsewhere in your program (Abstraction).

If you want to enforce some coding standards in your project, you may want to try using code analysis tools (like in Visual Studio) - They allow extensions, that you can incorporate to add you own code analysis rules.

Using code analysis, if you "forget" to add the delegates (although I don't see the point of forgetting it, as if the delegate is not used, it's not needed) you'll get a warning / error.

Comment: You may be right, but there are some times when you make some assumptions that even with good documentaion it's hard to remember after a while. I try to reuse my code but sometimes I can't remember what it the core and what it not (when it comes to delegates - it's hard for me to see the big picture...)

Answer (score 2):

One of your comments referenced the return type of event handler.  Are you more concerned with the type of the handler, or the data coming back from the event? If it's the latter, then this may help.  If not, then this solution won't be enough, but may help get you closer to what you're looking for.

All you have to do is declare your event handlers as generic event handlers in both the interface and your implementation and you can customize the return results.

Your conrete class would look like this:

```
public class ClsPictures : myInterface
{
    // Implementing the IProcess interface
    public event EventHandler<UpdateStatusEventArgs> UpdateStatusText;
    //no need for this anymore: public delegate void UpdateStatusEventHandler(string Status);

    public event EventHandler<StartedEventArgs> Started;
    //no need for this anymore: public delegate void StartedEventHandler();
}
```

Your interface would look like this:

```
public interface myInterface
{
   event EventHandler<StartedEventArgs> Started;
   event EventHandler<UpdateStatusEventArgs> UpdateStatusText;
}
```

Now that the event args are returning your types, you can hook them in any handler you define.

For reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The interface inherited within your derived class will remind you to define and link up the stuff you declared in it.

But you may also want to use it explicitly and you will still need to associate it to an object.

For example using an Inversion of Control pattern:

```
class Form1 : Form, IForm {
   public Form1() {
     Controls.Add(new Foo(this));
   }

   // Required to be defined here.
   void IForm.Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     ...
     // Cast qualifier expression to 'IForm' assuming you added a property for StatusBar.
     //((IForm) this).StatusBar.Text = $"Button clicked: ({e.RowIndex}, {e.SubItem}, {e.Model})";
   }
 }
```

You can try something like this.

```
interface IForm {
  void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e);
}


class Foo : UserControl {
  private Button btn = new Button();

  public Foo(IForm ctx) {
     btn.Name = "MyButton";
     btn.ButtonClick += ctx.Button_OnClick;
     Controls.Add(btn);
  }
}
```