# Definition for a delegate in an interface

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I have an interface, one of whose method definitions needs a delegate I've made as an argument. However, when implementing this interface, I'm not too sure how to have that delegate built in.

Is there a way to have it so that any class implementing this interface has a definition for that delegate? Would a using statement with the namespace be necessary?

Comment: Can you post the interface definition that you have now, and the intended implementation of this interface in a concrete class?

Comment: quick question have you tried a google search on how to add delegate to Interface..? also check out @JonSkeet post here assuming that you understand delegates and Interaces http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948721/how-to-add-delegate-to-interface-c-sharp

Comment: You can't *define* the delegate *in* the interface, but you can define the delegate separately and then *use* it in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure the `delegate` is defined in the same namespace as the interface. As long as both are `public` any library accessing yours will be able to see it.

If you need this signature to be different per interface, consider using a generic interface instead - but be wary in that generic constraints do *not* allow for constraint to `Delegate`, `Enum`, or `ValueType`. If you can lock down the number of arguments, you may be able specify each argument as a generic constraint instead.